# Rounded button without losing style

Tags: android, button, material-design, drawable, material-components-android

i'm trying to make a simple rounded button like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjtd3.png)
starting from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PptJ1.png)

The problem is that i don't want to lose the style (the ripple and the color change when you press it and the shadow). that would happen using a state-drawable as background.

How can i achieve it?

Comment: Photoshop your button and take only the necessary part and save it as a png file then use it as the background for the button.

Comment: I have created these in my app, will post answer soon.

Comment: @Khemraj Ok i'm interested

Comment: You can extend the Button class and create a custom button while changing what needs to be changed but keeping the style.

Comment: @RedM Yes but there is no default method like setCornerRadius, that's my  problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            style="@style/buttonApp"
            android:text="Normal" />
```

in `res>values>styles.xml` put this. and change padding, colors if you need.

```
<style name="buttonApp" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/appButtonHeight</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_button_orange</item>
</style>
```

**You will get required press effect by 1 drawable for post 21 version, like below, but pre 21 version do not support ripple effect so you have to make some drawables background for press and non press effect, i have included final solution here**

`bg_button_orange.xml` in `res>drawables-v21>`

**(this is after 21 version android)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorGreenAlpha" />
            <corners android:radius="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_not_selected" />
</ripple>
```

`bg_button_orange.xml` in `res>drawables>`

**(this is for pre 21 version android)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_selected" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_selected" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_not_selected" />
</selector>
```

`bg_button_not_selected.xml` in `res>drawables`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorGreenLight" />
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/appButtonRadius" />
</shape>
```

`bg_button_not_selected.xml` in `res>drawables`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorGreen" />
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/appButtonRadius" />
</shape>
```

put in `res>values>dimens.xml`

```
<dimen name="appButtonHeight">60dp</dimen>
<dimen name="appButtonRadius">30dp</dimen>
```

put in `res>values>colors.xml`

```
<color name="colorGreen">#009688</color>
<color name="colorGreenAlpha">#b0009688</color>
<color name="colorGreenLight">#27d4c4</color>
```

**Button height should be double than button radius to get exact round corners.**

You will get button like belo image with ripple effect on post 21 version and press effect before 21 version.

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`MaterialButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) in the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) with the **`app:cornerRadius`** attribute.

Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:text="NORMAL"
        app:cornerRadius="16dp"
        ../>
```

[image]